# Como verificar se um objeto possui uma string?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Estou com o seguinte problema, preciso verificar se um objeto possui uma certa string, esse objeto vem do autocomplete do google places API.

Esse é um json de retorno, por exemplo:

```
{
"address_components": [{
    "long_name": "1219",
    "short_name": "1219",
    "types": ["street_number"]
}, {
    "long_name": "Avenida Corrientes",
    "short_name": "Av. Corrientes",
    "types": ["route"]
}, {
    "long_name": "San Nicolas",
    "short_name": "San Nicolas",
    "types": ["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political"]
}, {
    "long_name": "Comuna 1",
    "short_name": "Comuna 1",
    "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
}, {
    "long_name": "Buenos Aires",
    "short_name": "CABA",
    "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
}, {
    "long_name": "Argentina",
    "short_name": "AR",
    "types": ["country", "political"]
}, {
    "long_name": "C1043",
    "short_name": "C1043",
    "types": ["postal_code"]
}, {
    "long_name": "AAM",
    "short_name": "AAM",
    "types": ["postal_code_suffix"]
}],
"adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">Av. Corrientes 1219</span>, <span class=\"postal-code\">C1043AAM</span> <span class=\"locality\">CABA</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Argentina</span>",
"formatted_address": "Av. Corrientes 1219, C1043AAM CABA, Argentina",
"geometry": {
    "location": {
        "lat": -34.6037445,
        "lng": -58.383988199999976
    },
    "viewport": {
        "south": -34.60514058029149,
        "west": -58.3853329302915,
        "north": -34.6024426197085,
        "east": -58.38263496970848
    }
},
"icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
"id": "125f7a07fb81d10e98cec399869aaa694cb4b61f",
"name": "Av. Corrientes 1219",
"place_id": "ChIJC05_5cXKvJURhKX6uVXO7eE",
"reference": "CmRbAAAA5p8P3NP9ZMf2RjufMeNs8TZCrG4xe5ItjNYkKoYCcD8wpVG_bujknZM_8cj2k1e2Dtqg1bFjzxSkHTgH1o9MYIiBt1_bozOcgKbSXf95KJNttYd-2pg-E_iKxPH5eZHfEhAl0QPng-2n3Es9Q20B7c-ZGhTW6b2CtvBfBZuA_qUSLJvvngXGMA",
"scope": "GOOGLE",
"types": ["street_address"],
"url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=Av.+Corrientes+1219,+C1043AAM+CABA,+Argentina&ftid=0x95bccac5e57f4e0b:0xe1edce55b9faa584",
"utc_offset": -180,
"vicinity": "San Nicolas",
"html_attributions": []
}
```

O que eu preciso é verificar se dentro do **"address_components"** existem os tipos **"postal_code"** ou **"postal_code_suffix"**.

O que eu fiz foi percorrer os objetos porém não consigo buscar o postal_code ou o postal_code_suffix sem passar a posição "manualmente".

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(JSON.stringify(place));

for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
    var arrayTipos = [];                                                               
    arrayTipos.push(place.address_components[i].types[j]);
    var arrayValido = arrayTipos.indexOf('postal_code_suffix');

    if (arrayValido == 0) {
      var postalCode = place.address_components[6].long_name;
      var postalCodeSufix = place.address_components[7].long_name;
      var fullPostalCode = postalCodeSufix + postalCode;                                                       
      $('#codigoPostal').val(fullPostalCode);
    } else {
      $('#codigoPostal').val('');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: É genérico demais fazer `JSON.stringify(obj).includes('postal_code')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) para encontrar os objetos que possuam **postal_code** ou **postal_code_suffix** no array `types` e utilizar eles para retornar o código postal.

Utilizando a função `getPostalCode` do snippet o seu código ficaria assim

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
$('#codigoPostal').val(getPostalCode(place));
```

```js
function getPostalCode(json) {
  var addrs = json.address_components
  var code = addrs.find(addr => addr.types.indexOf('postal_code') !== -1)
  var suffix = addrs.find(addr => addr.types.indexOf('postal_code_suffix') !== -1)
  if (!code || !suffix) {
    return ''
  }
  return code.long_name + suffix.long_name
}

var place = {
  "address_components": [{
    "long_name": "1219",
    "short_name": "1219",
    "types": ["street_number"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Avenida Corrientes",
    "short_name": "Av. Corrientes",
    "types": ["route"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "San Nicolas",
    "short_name": "San Nicolas",
    "types": ["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Comuna 1",
    "short_name": "Comuna 1",
    "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Buenos Aires",
    "short_name": "CABA",
    "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Argentina",
    "short_name": "AR",
    "types": ["country", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "C1043",
    "short_name": "C1043",
    "types": ["postal_code"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "AAM",
    "short_name": "AAM",
    "types": ["postal_code_suffix"]
  }],
  "adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">Av. Corrientes 1219</span>, <span class=\"postal-code\">C1043AAM</span> <span class=\"locality\">CABA</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Argentina</span>",
  "formatted_address": "Av. Corrientes 1219, C1043AAM CABA, Argentina",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": -34.6037445,
      "lng": -58.383988199999976
    },
    "viewport": {
      "south": -34.60514058029149,
      "west": -58.3853329302915,
      "north": -34.6024426197085,
      "east": -58.38263496970848
    }
  },
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
  "id": "125f7a07fb81d10e98cec399869aaa694cb4b61f",
  "name": "Av. Corrientes 1219",
  "place_id": "ChIJC05_5cXKvJURhKX6uVXO7eE",
  "reference": "CmRbAAAA5p8P3NP9ZMf2RjufMeNs8TZCrG4xe5ItjNYkKoYCcD8wpVG_bujknZM_8cj2k1e2Dtqg1bFjzxSkHTgH1o9MYIiBt1_bozOcgKbSXf95KJNttYd-2pg-E_iKxPH5eZHfEhAl0QPng-2n3Es9Q20B7c-ZGhTW6b2CtvBfBZuA_qUSLJvvngXGMA",
  "scope": "GOOGLE",
  "types": ["street_address"],
  "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=Av.+Corrientes+1219,+C1043AAM+CABA,+Argentina&ftid=0x95bccac5e57f4e0b:0xe1edce55b9faa584",
  "utc_offset": -180,
  "vicinity": "San Nicolas",
  "html_attributions": []
}
var postalCode = getPostalCode(place)
console.log(postalCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso você tenha certeza que a palavra **postal_code** ou **postal_code_suffix** não esteja em outro lugar, a não ser dentro do `array` `types`, você pode usar:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
var postalCode = jsonStr.includes('postal_code');
var postalCodeSuffix = jsonStr.includes('postal_code_suffix');

// Se true, existe a palavra postal_code ou postal_code_suffix no seu objeto
var ans = postalCode || postalCodeSuffix;
```

(Se houver uma `string` no `JSON` como: **postal_code_x** ele irá pegar também, isso também pode ser um problema)

---

Caso você não tenha certeza, você pode usar o método `some` que retorna `true` caso algum dos objetos no `array` retorne **verdadeiro** para a função passada como parâmetro:

```
// Se true, existe a palavra postal_code ou postal_code_suffix dentro do array types
var ans = obj['address_components'].some( function(addr) { 
  return addr.types.some( function(type) {
      return type === 'postal_code' || type === 'postal_code_suffix';
  });
});
```

Eu particulamente usaria a segunda opção, por ser mais **segura**.